# C program and Macros

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

I have some thing like this:

```
#define num1 6
#define num2 3
```

I want to **multiply these 2 macros** and convert **it into string** and store in one more macro.
Please give your suggestions how to do this.

Comment: Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Why a macro? Converting to a string cannot be done this way.

Comment: If you want to do that in the preprocessor, then it's not really possible (unless you consider a very long cascade of `#if` directives a possibility)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a third macro which is the result of multiplying these two numbers, you can do it like this:

```
#define num1 6
#define num2 3
#define num3 (num1*num2)
```

You can then print it like this:

```
printf("num3=%d\n", num3);
```

If you want to store that value in a string, you can do this:

```
char num3str[10];
sprintf(num3str, "%d", num3);
```